# Invalid function type [DIV0] for window function in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake, which is getting loaded from multiple tables through transformations.
The table is loading fine in postgres.

But when I am running in snowflake it is giving me the error: DIVISION BY ZERO, through analysis, I found out that div by 0 is the cause of it.

So I used div0 function over there as:

```
 div0(col_1 , sum(col_1)) over(partition by year) as final_col
```

but that is throwing an error as below:

```
         Invalid function type [DIV0] for window function
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DIV0 is not a windowed function. It should be applied on top of windowed function. Position of parantehsis matters:

```
SELECT div0(col_1 , sum(col_1)) over(partition by year) as final_col
=>
SELECT div0(col_1 , (sum(col_1) over(partition by year)) as final_col
```